# gsub variable regardless of case

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have the following code which will set a highlight for any parts of the phrase where the word is.  I would like this to function regardless of case but I am struggling with the syntax. I believe I need to add /i somewhere, but I do not know where.

```
params.fetch('phrase').gsub(params.fetch('word'),
  '<span class="ko-highlight">' + params.fetch('word') + '</span>')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
params.fetch('phrase').gsub(/#{params.fetch('word')}/i, '<span class="ko-highlight">' + params.fetch('word') + '</span>')
```

Comment: Thanks! Any clue how to make the output match the case of the original word?

Comment: That should be already the case, since you replace the match with `params.fetch('word') `, or?